# ingress rule k8s specific path

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to implement the next rules. I have two services which are pointing to different pods. I have a path /rest-api  and /rest-api/topology. I want to point one of them to a svc and another one to a different one.

Here is my attempt, but it seems something is wrong.

```yaml
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: writer-svc
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /rest-api(/topology|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
            name: normal-svc
            port:
              number: 8443
        path: /rest-api(/|$)(?!topology|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
```

Comment: Since this code doesn't produce any errors, more details than "something is wrong" would be nice, because depending on what you use this ingress with, "wrong" can take many forms.

Comment: so originaly there was just 1 block with /rest-api(/|$)(.*) which is working just fine, if i add 1 more block which it will  point to  another svc i will got 500 error code

Comment: Doesn't sound right. I've been doing different combos with ingress, even making different services for same app, and it all worked

Answer (score 0):

Here's my normal approach:

```
spec: 
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
  - host: my.server.co
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: 
          service:
            name: yeaboi1
            port:  
              number: 80
      - path: /api/coolstuff
        pathType: Prefix
        backend: 
          service:
            name: yeaboi2
            port:  
              number: 80
```

Works just fine.
The obvious difference I see from yours is absence of unneeded regex.
Maybe try it this way?

Comment: i did a try without regex but  still when i  have 2 blocks i will get 500

Comment: Doesn't sound like ingress problem. What does happen when you have just the other service? Still 500? If so, is there anything in logs for pods related to that service?

Comment: if just the  one with  rest-api  all good,but i found the issue, is related to rewrite-target annotation. which is /rest-api/$2 butbecause i  dont use nginx plus where i can have multiple  rewrite dependent  on the svc i just created a new ingress and that's it. thanks for help

Comment: Glad I could help. And should've asked for ingress yaml outright. Rewrite-target is quite unfriendly and can easily break stuff.